# Vuejs how to auto select dropdown value from database

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select option of

```
<label>Select Teacher</label>
<select class="form-control" name="teacher" v-model="form.teacher" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('teacher') }">
  <option :selected="teacher.id == form.teacher ? selected : null"   :value="teacher.id" v-for="teacher in teachers" :key="teacher.id">{{teacher.fullname}} - {{teacher.course}}</option>
</select>
```

The form object

```
form: new Form({
    id: '',
    room: '',
    teacher: '',
    subject: '',
    days: '',
    term: '',
    sem: '',
    start_time: '',
    end_time: '',
    schoolyr: '',
    scid:'',
}),
```

The function for editing

```
editModal(schedule) {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show')
    this.form.fill(schedule)
    console.log(this.form)
},
```

The console says

```
Form {…}
busy: false
successful: false
errors: Errors
originalData: Object
id: 7
room: undefined
teacher: undefined
subject: undefined
days: undefined
term: "2"
sem: undefined
start_time: "10:30 PM"
end_time: "12:30 AM"
schoolyr: undefined
scid: 1
```

I got some of the data like because they are in a textbox input type. but the `select` tag does not seems to work.

I tried to write this `:selected="teacher.id == form.teacher ? selected : null"` but it seems nothing is happening. I am using `vform` package to submit and edit forms. The method `this.forms.fill(data)` works but only in textboxes and not in dropdown and radio buttons.

Can someone know what should I do about this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name="teacher" v-model="form.teacher_id" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('teacher') }">
  <option :selected="teacher.id == form.teacher ? selected : null"   :value="teacher.id" v-for="teacher in teachers" :key="teacher.id">{{teacher.fullname}} - {{teacher.course}}</option>
</select>
```

I figured it out by adding a `teacher_id` in my data component and changing the `teachers` to `teacher_id` and thats why it becomes undefined.